# Automapper (4.2.1) throwing an exception "missing map..." even though the map is created on the line above

Tags: c#, automapper

I’ve been trying to upgrade to Automapper 4, but without luck. This throws an exception that the mapping is missing while it’s not

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Journal, JournalDTO>();
        cfg.CreateMap<JournalDTO, Journal>();
    });

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
var journals = mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Journal>>(context.Journal.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<JournalDTO>());
```

My old working code is this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Journal, JournalDTO>().ReverseMap();
var journals = Mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Journal>>    
          (context.Journal.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<JournalDTO>());
```

I don’t see what the problem is, I followed [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API)

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the static and non-static APIs, you need to pick one or the other. The piece that's getting mixed is ProjectTo, the non-static version takes the MapperConfiguration as an argument.

```
var journals = mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Journal>>(context.Journal.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<JournalDTO>(configuration));
```

The static API is still supported, but you just have to use Mapper.Initialize, if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works :) I did not notice that I need to pass the configuration to the ProjectTo.

Comment: In my case, I just totally forgot to pass it once and was racking my brain as to why the map was missing! Thanks for the reminder!